# What ISN'T included in SQL Server snapshot replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

When creating a publication in SQL Server 2012 I get the options to include articles of type:

1. tables
2. views
3. stored procedures
4. UDFs

Since this list didn't include user-defined types, I was expecting those NOT to be replicated. But happily they were! (i.e. user-defined table types were replicated)

So question: What **CANNOT** be replicated in SQL Server? Also, why WERE the types replicated? Do they count as 'tables'?

Comment: Did you not include that as an article?

Comment: no. there was no option to include types as articles so far as I can tell. i only had views/sps/functions/tables

Comment: You added one of the object that is created using a user defined type?

Comment: no. in the source database there were some table-types defined. I didn't specify those types to be replicated, but they were anyway. While this is a good thing, i wouldn't consider a type to be a table, view, sp, or udf. but i would still consider it to be an article, so I would like to know why it was replicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might not be a full answer. But this is too long to put in a comment.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/publish-data-and-database-objects

**Publishing User-Defined Types and Alias Data Types**

> Columns that use user-defined types or alias data types are replicated
>   to Subscribers like other columns. The CREATE TYPEstatement for each
>   replicated type is executed at the Subscriber before the table is
>   created. In the case of user-defined types, the associated assembly is
>   also copied to each Subscriber. Changes to user-defined types and
>   alias data types are not replicated to Subscribers.
>
> If a type is defined in a database, but it is not referenced in any
>   columns when a publication is created, the type is not copied to
>   Subscribers. If you subsequently create a column of that type in the
>   database and want to replicate it, you must first manually copy the
>   type (and the associated assembly for a user-defined type) to each
>   Subscriber.

**What CANNOT be replicated in SQL Server?**

Anything not listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/publish-data-and-database-objects) cannot be replicated.

Comment: my types are referenced by stored procedures, and not used as column types. They are all table types